# how to create a comma delimited array from an ordered select box in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html

How can I create an array of items from a generated list using a select box to order the items and deliminate them by a comma.

Example...

I have a list of items generated by the id in the database with a select box associated with the item.

```
<?php
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT id, title FROM songs WHERE id='$id' ORDER BY title ASC");

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $id = $row['id'];
    $title = $row['title'];
    $song_chart .= '

      <div id="$id">

        <select>
          <option val="1">1</option>
          <option val="2">2</option>
          <option val="3">3</option>
          <option val="4">4</option>
          //etc...
        </select>

        <a href="page.php?id='.$id.'">'.$title.'</a>

      </div>';
  }
$song_chart .= '<button></button>';
echo $song_chart;
?>
```

I have multiple items that I would like to select a value for.

If the value is greater than 0 than I want to grab the 'id' from the item the select is associated with and order all of the items by the selection (not the id).

Then I would like to post the information and place it into a comma delimited array to insert into my database.

I currently do not have any code that I have actually tried, I am really not sure how to go about this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

The output of the above would look like this...

```
<div id="1">
  <select>
    <option val="1">1</option>
    <option val="2">2</option>
    <option val="3">3</option>
    <option val="4">4</option>
    //etc...
  </select>

  <a href="page.php?id=1">one</a>

</div>
<div id="2">
  <select>
    <option val="1">1</option>
    <option val="2">2</option>
    <option val="3">3</option>
    <option val="4">4</option>
    //etc...
  </select>

  <a href="page.php?id=2">two</a>

</div>
<div id="3">
  <select>
    <option val="1">1</option>
    <option val="2">2</option>
    <option val="3">3</option>
    <option val="4">4</option>
    //etc...
  </select>

  <a href="page.php?id=3">three</a>

</div>
<div id="4">
  <select>
    <option val="1">1</option>
    <option val="2">2</option>
    <option val="3">3</option>
    <option val="4">4</option>
    //etc...
  </select>

  <a href="page.php?id=4">four</a>

</div>

<button></button>
```

Then on submit I would like to reorganize the generated id's accourding to the selected value and place then in an array/string like so...

```
var arr = '2, 3, 1, 4';
```

and post them to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came with a solution with the help from Diodeus (Thanks).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.selection').value(""); // clears the values
  $('selection option').click(function(){ // when option is clicked

    s=new Array(); // create array
    $("select option:selected").each(function(){
     // check to see which values are selected
      var v = $(this).val();

      if(v != ""){ // if the value is not empty.
        s.push(v); 
      }

    });

  });
  $("#submitList").click(function(){
    if(s != ""){
      alert(s);//or submit the list
    }
  });
});
```

I also changed a few things in the html output.

```
<div id="3">
  <select class='selection'>
    <option></option>
    <option val="1,id">1</option>
    <option val="2,id">2</option>
    <option val="3,id">3</option>
    <option val="4,id">4</option>                      
    //etc...                    
  </select>
  <a href="page.php?id=3">three</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, in this situation, it's easier to encode the data in the value of the OPTION

```
<div id="3">
  <select>
    <option val="1">1</option>
    <option val="2">2</option>
    <option val="3">3</option>
    <option val="4">4</option>
    //etc...
  </select>

  <a href="page.php?id=3">three</a>

</div>
```

Becomes:

```
<div id="3">
  <select>
    <option val="3,1">1</option>
    <option val="3,2">2</option>
    <option val="3,3">3</option>
    <option val="3,4">4</option>
    //etc...
  </select>

  <a href="page.php?id=3">three</a>

</div>
```

Embed the ID in the data. Comma separated.

Comment: Thank you @Diodeus for the response, but the problem is that select multiple will allow someone to select multiple options within the select element. What I want to do is get the single value of the selection and the item 'id' from each generated item associated with the select box in the list, then order them according to the selected value.

Comment: Put all of the values you need in the "value" and use comma-separated.

Comment: I apologize, I am relativily new to programming. Could you expound on that possibly with a simple code example? I promise that I am not trying to fish for an answer, just a means to an end would be nice. Thanks

Comment: The HTML you have posted not not fully describe what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: You're showing PHP code. The issues is on the client, so show your HTML output. The source code has no relevancy here.

Comment: But I am using php to generate the HTML output from my database. As shown above I am compounding <div>'s filled with a select box and a ref tagged title ordered by the title. I want to grab the id that is associated with the generated title and select box, lets just say the id is "1" and the value that I have selected lets just say "4", then another lets say the id is "4" with the selection of "1" and then submit them based off the selected value. I understand this is a client side issue, but I am not sure how to do this, which is why I am reaching out for help.

Comment: Well after some brain thumping I was finally able to come up with the solution. Even though you did not give me the answer I was looking for you did give me the answer, what you did give me was very helpful and I appreciate the time you spent with me thank you very much. +1